# How do I get a listing of only plain files in a directory using Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a way in Perl to list the plain files of a directory. Files only, no directories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` functions in conjunction with `-f` file test operator:

```
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die $!;
while(my $f = readdir $dh) {
    next unless (-f "$some_dir/$f");
    print "$some_dir/$f\n";
}
closedir $dh;
```

Comment: File::Find is the more general, better answer, in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't want to do a depth-first search of an entire tree, File::Find is not the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to list all files in a directory is to use the `read_dir` function from the CPAN module [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);

my $dir = './';
my @files = grep { -f } read_dir($dir);
```

It performs opendir checks for you.  Keep in mind that it includes any "hidden" files (those which begin with a dot).  This does not recursively list files in subdirectories of the specified directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the file test "operator" (really a function) to check for what sort of file you want.

In the simple case where you want to scan the current directory use a file glob with grep:

```
my @files = grep -f, <*>;
```

Otherwise, you can work with a directory handle:

```
opendir my $dh, $dirpath;

my @files = grep -f, readdir( $dh );

closedir $dh;
```

See [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html), [closedir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html), [-X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), and [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/lib/File/Find.pm). It's a core module.

```
use File::Find;
find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
sub wanted 
{ 
   my $file = shift;
   return unless (-f $file);
   #process file
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it uses already-written-and-tested libraries. File::Find is in core Perl, so you don't need to install anything.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will recursively list all files in all subdirectories of the specified directory.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) operator.

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = "/tmp/foo";
opendir my $dh, $dir
  or die "$0: opendir: $!";

while (defined(my $name = readdir $dh)) {
  next unless -f "$dir/$name";
  print "$name\n";
}
```

Running it:

```
$ ls -F /tmp/foo
a  b  c  d/

$ ./prog.pl 
b
c
a
```

As you can see, the names come out in the order they're stored physically on the filesystem, which isn't necessarily sorted.

To go the quick-and-dirty route, you could also use the glob operator as in

```
print map { s!^.*/!!; "$_\n" }
      grep !-d $_ =>
      </tmp/foo/*>;
```

Note that you'll have to remove directories from the result, and the glob operator doesn't return files whose names begin with dots.

Answer (score 2):

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule/) from CPAN makes this utterly trivial:

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in( $directory );
```

This finds all the files in the given directory or any of its subdirectories. I recommend this because of the combination of extreme flexibility and simplicity.

Comment: Can this be used to find all files in a path like:

a/**/**/b/**/c.txt

Comment: Sure! You just need to add a name() call to that after file - but be sure to use Unix-style wildcards (single-asterisk). You can also use regexes there if you want to: name('.*something[A-Z].*\.foo'). So you'd say File::Find::Rule->file->name('a/*/*/b/*/c.txt')->in($directory) to find your example file.